# Can't set "class" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

These lines in jquery making me bad:

```
var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{width: select.outerWidth(), className:'styledSelect', html:'<div class="selectBox"></div>'});
var dropDown = $('<ul>',{className:'dropDown'});
```

It should set the class attribute "class="styledselect" in the output, but the attribute's name is "classname":

```
<div classname="styledSelect">
    <ul classname="dropDown" style="display: none;">...</ul>
</div>
```

when I change it simply to `{class:'dropDown'}` ist works in firefox, but not in other browsers.

help please...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
{'class': 'dropDown'}
```

`class` is a *future reserved word* in JavaScript, so you must specify it as a string inside object literals for some browsers, notably IE 8 and lower.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
{ "class": "dropDown" }
```

or add `.addClass("drowDown")` to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would to use the following:

```
var dropDown = $('<ul>').addClass('dropDown');
```

Use the jQuery native methods, they're made for this. It's also much more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
{'class':'dropDown'}
```

should work in all browsers. Alternatively, you could try

```
dropDown.addClass("dropDown");
```

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't, it fails in older versions of some browsers.

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, it will not work in all browsers. In fact, it should not work in any browser (even though it does in some)